# Concatenating Unique Values from List of Dictionaries with sames Keys in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I am working with a list of dictionaries and am trying to combine them into one with the following conditions:

1. The dictionaries in the list all have the same keys, and the new dictionary will as well
2. If the values for a given key across all dictionaries is the same, then that value will appear once in the value for the new dictionary
3. If the values for a given key across as dictionaries are unique, then the value for that key in the new dictionary will be a comma seperated string of all the values

So really what I am trying to do is create a set for a given key across multiple dictionaries, and create a comma seperated string of that set for the value in a new dictionary.  To help visualize, given:

```
data = [ {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},  
         {"key1": "value4", "key2": "value5", "key3": "value3"}, 
         {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value8", "key3": "value3"} ]
```

I want to make a new dictionary out of data that would like as follows:

```
myDict = {"key1": "value1, value4", "key2": "value2, value5, value8", "key3": "value3"}
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presumed two things here - that order of the values was not important to you, and that you did not mean to have two of the same keys in each dictionary (which I've replaced with `"key3"`):

```
>>> data = [ {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},
...          {"key1": "value4", "key2": "value5", "key3": "value3"},
...          {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value8", "key3": "value3"} ]
>>>
>>> keylist = data[0].keys()
>>> mydata = dict((k,', '.join(set(map(lambda d: d[k], data)))) for k in keylist)
>>> mydata
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value5, value2, value8', 'key1': 'value4, value1'}
```

Answer (score 5):

`collections.defaultdict` is your friend.

```
from collections import defaultdict
temp_dict = defaultdict(set)
for item in data:
   for key, value in item.items():
       temp_dict[key].add(value)
```

That gives you a dict in the form `{"key1": ["value1", "value4"]}` - if you want actual comma-separated strings for the values then you can join them:

```
my_dict = {}
for key, value in temp_dict.items():
    my_dict[key] = ", ".join(value)
```

Comment: How have I never seen `defaultdict` before?  That is most righteous. +1 from me.

Comment: very cool solution as well.  went with nates as its slightly more direct but this is awesome.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: from itertools import chain
In [12]: dict([ (key, ",".join(set([elem[key] for elem in data]))) for key in set(list(chain(*[d.keys() for d in data])))])
Out[12]: {'key1': 'value4,value1', 'key2': 'value5,value2,value8', 'key3': 'value3'}
```